# Error Qt + Beagle bone + Deployment

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, beagleboard

I tried to deploy my application created on Qt, but i get this error when i deploy ...

```
/home/root/2_boutton_2_capture: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGuiE.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me to solve it
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The shared library **libQtGuiE.so.4** is missing on the Beagle Bone.
If you're using Angstrom, you must install the **libqtguie** package on BeagleBone.

Comment: I tried 'opkg install libqtguie' and 'opkg install libqtgui' but the package is unknown ... Can you tell me please how to do?

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution

Just do what it is suggesting first:
opkg update
Then,
opkg install qt4-embedded --force-depends